# The packet goes through the other router

Tags: ip, tcp, ping, traceroute, vrrp

I want to connect two hosts in parallel with two different models of virtual routers.
These are made redundant by VRRP.

Originally, packets are sent through only one of the routers.
However, when the packet is sent, it goes through two routers. This results in duplicate ping packets.The traceroute now looks like this.
host1：$ traceroute -I 192.168.1.1

1. 192.168.0.2
2. 192.168.1.3
3. 192.168.1.1

Why do the packets go through the other router?

The network configuration is shown below.

- Host1(Ubuntu20.04)

  - IP Address:192.168.0.1
  - gateway:192.168.0.5
- Host2(Ubuntu20.04)

  - IP Address:192.168.1.1
  - gateway:192.168.1.5
- Physical Router(Ubuntu20.04)
  There are two virtual routers created by vagrant and Virtualbox inside.
- Virtual Router(Vyos)

  - Use vagrant box "kun432/vyos"
  - eth1:192.168.0.2
  - eth2:192.168.1.2
- Virtual Router(vSRX)

  - Use vagrant box "juniper/ffp-12.1X47-D15.4-packetmode"
  - ge-0/0/1:192.168.0.3
  - ge-0/0/2:192.168.1.3
- 192.168.0.0/24 network Virtual IP Address: 192.168.0.5
- 192.168.1.0/24 network Virtual IP Address: 192.168.1.5
- NetworkBridge: bridge-utils

◆VRRP

Networking:[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem the way VRRP works. Normally it doesn't get packet duplicated. Please, provide the details: a network diagram, what software you use to build your virtual routers and its configuration; you may mask sensitive information like public names or public IP addresses.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't noticed a picture because of bad formatting. Thanks to @Rob who fixed it.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov
Thank you for your comment. Detailed network settings are shown. The image is in bad format because it has no more than 10 reputations.  Our apologies.

Comment: What is the vrrp configuration? What does logs show? Do they indicate that VRRP is functioning? Or does both routers assume the other router is down?

Comment: @vidarlo
Thank you for your comment.
In this network configuration, we are dynamically changing the VRRP priority value to verify that the router through which host 1 switches to host 2.
To perform VRRP switching, we have configured a common Virtual IP address of 192.168.0.5 for eth1 on Vyos and ge-0/0/1 on vSRX, and 192.168.1.5 for eth2 on Vyos and ge-0/0/2 on vSRX. Both routers are up and running, one acting as master and the other as backup.

Comment: Have you actually verified that they can see each other and have the correct status for the other router?

Comment: @vidarlo
Yes, I have checked the communication between arp -a and ping on vyos and vsrx. However, ping packets from vsrx to vyos seem to be duplicated. Also, when vsrx is the master, ping packets from host1 to host2 are not duplicated.

Comment: for me it looks like a homework assignment... could this be?

Comment: @djdomi
Sorry, does that mean that the network configuration shown in the attached image is not feasible?

Comment: we help businesses administrators to fix the real network. And not trainees that want to cheat and shortcut on there home works from school ;)